# Hover/mouseenter event triggers jQuery UI's 'animate' repetitively

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, navigation, hover, mouseenter

So I have a navigation and I'm using jQuery's UI animate to make the list item slide down out of view, change colour, and to then slide back up, revealing the button in a different color.

The problem I'm getting is that whenever I hover over the list item, the hover event is triggered continually until the mouse has left.

Even stranger, is that it appears that the mouseleave event triggers right after the hover event, regardless of whether the mouse has actually left the list item. This happens whether I used hover or mouseenter.

Here's what I have:
HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
        <a href="services.html"><li>Services</li></a>
        <a href="portfolio.html"><li>Portfolio</li></a>
        <a href="contact.php"><li>Contact</li></a>
        <a href="about.html"><li>About</li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

jQuery:

```
$("nav li").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({bottom:"-50px"},"fast", function(){$(this).css('background','orange');$(this).css('color','#fff');});
        $(this).animate({bottom:"-0px"},"fast");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({bottom:"-50px"},"fast", function(){$(this).css('background','white');$(this).css('color','#333');});
        $(this).animate({bottom:"-0px"},"fast");
    });
```

CSS:

```
nav{
float:right;
margin-top:91px;
}
nav ul, nav ul li{
display:inline;
}
nav li{
margin-left:10px;
position:relative;
padding:5px 20px;
color:#A29874;
background-color:#fff;
border-top-right-radius:5px;
border-top-left-radius:5px;
 }

nav a{
position:relative;
text-decoration:none;
 }
```

I can achieve the effect I'm after if I very slowly bring my mouse into one of the list items, just a few pixels inside. This task, which seems as if it should be relatively easy, is driving me nuts.

I've scoured the net and have tried things such as unbinding the mouseenter event, using a conditional to run the animation only after the mouseleave event has triggered to no avail.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, preferably before I go bald.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that you're moving the element so it is no longer under the mouse. Therefore obviously `mouseleave()` is triggered. You can avoid this by triggering the animation on hover of the `a` tag, but target the `li` with the animation. See: http://jsfiddle.net/aN4g4/50/

Here's your new js:

```
$("nav a").mouseenter(function(){
    var $li = $(this).find('li');
    $li.stop(true,true).animate({bottom:"-50px"},"fast",
        function(){
            $li.css({'background':'orange','color':'#fff'});
        });
    $li.stop(true,true).animate({bottom:"-0px"},"fast");
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var $li = $(this).find('li');
    $li.stop(true,true).animate({bottom:"-50px"},"fast",
        function(){
            $li.css({'background':'white','color':'#333'});
        });
    $li.animate({bottom:"-0px"},"fast");
});
```

You may have noticed that the callback function which fires after the animation finished has been optimized a bit. You can pass multiple CSS properties in this way: `.css({'prop1':'val1','prop2':val2'})` Also, I have optimized the code so you're not generating a lot of jQuery objects because that is slow. (notice the `var $li` line.)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Also, thanks for optimizing those bits of code (Always good to pickup on best practices). You, Sir, have made my day!

Answer (score 0):

try to set yours `li` as `position: relative;`

i just "paste" your code and set relative yours `<li>`

the result was a little funny.

**See here:**  http://jsfiddle.net/aN4g4/47/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Although the nav li are set to relative already. I'll add the current CSS to my edit.

Comment: Nope. Take a look in the demo.

Comment: The demo is certainly acting strangely. Here it is with some extra styling: http://jsfiddle.net/aN4g4/49/ . My main problem is that the hover event is triggered regardless of whether the mouse has left the button, so the button constantly shifts up and down if the mouse moves.